# Need help aligning form with CSS

Tags: css, forms, alignment

Hey I have a very simply question but I am not quite sure how to achieve this without using HTML tables. Basically what I want is the label to to be on the left with 3 radio button to its right. The thing is, I want each individual radio button to be aligned vertically.

For example:

Label - choice 1
..........- choice 2
..........- choice 3

The HTML structure I am using is as follows:

```
<label for="radio1">Label</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio1"> <span class="form-span">Option 1</span>
<input type="radio" name="radio1"> <span class="form-span">Option 2</span>
<input type="radio" name="radio1"> <span class="form-span">Option 3</span>
```

Can anyone help me to align the form properly?

Thanks :)

**EDIT**

I found a very simply solution and was wondering whether is it an acceptable one: could you please tell me if it acceptable according to HTML standards?

```
<label for="radio1">Label</label>
<span class="form-span"><input type="radio" name="radio1"> <span class="form-label">Option 1</span></span>
<span class="form-span"><input type="radio" name="radio1"> <span class="form-label">Option 2</span></span>
```

and CSS:

```
.form-span {display:block}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to wrap everything in a div:

```
<div class="container">
   <label for="radio1">Label</label>
   <input type="radio" name="radio1"> <span class="form-span">Option 1</span>
   <input type="radio" name="radio1"> <span class="form-span">Option 2</span>
   <input type="radio" name="radio1"> <span class="form-span">Option 3</span>
</div>
```

and then add the following CSS:

```
   .container{height:200px;}
   label{float:left; height:100%;}
   input{float:left;}
   .form-span{display:block;}
```

Check out this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yUsyQ/)** to see a live example.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<label for="radio1">Label</label>
<div id="parentDiv">
<input type="radio" name="radio1"> <span class="form-span">Option 1</span>
<input type="radio" name="radio1"> <span class="form-span">Option 2</span>
<input type="radio" name="radio1"> <span class="form-span">Option 3</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parentDiv, label, input, span {
   float:left;
}

input {
   clear:both;
   margin-left:5px;
}

span {
   margin-left:5px;
}
```

Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/gNHB7/